# Why does this Rust code cause a stack overflow without recursion or looping?

Tags: rust, stack-overflow

I cannot figure out why this Rust code causes a stack overflow.

```
enum SlidingAttackTable {
    Rook([[u64; 4096]; 64]),
    Bishop([[u64; 512]; 64]),
}

fn init_all() -> (SlidingAttackTable, SlidingAttackTable, [u64; 64], [u64; 64], [usize; 64]) {
    return (SlidingAttackTable::Bishop([[0; 512]; 64]), SlidingAttackTable::Rook([[0; 4096]; 64]), [0; 64], [0; 64], [0; 64]);
}

fn main() {
    println!("start");
    let (bishop_attack_table, rook_attack_table, bishop_masks, bishop_magic_numbers, bishop_relevant_bits) = init_all();
}
```

I have tried commenting out everything but `println!("start")` and it printed "start" with no error. Somehow, when I add just these few lines of code back in, it crashes before even getting to that line and printing "start". There is no looping or recursion going on here that I can detect, so I have no idea how to begin diagnosing this problem.

Comment: Because that's a giant array on stack?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Is 4k of items really that gigantic in 2023?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[u64; 4096]` takes 2^(3+12) bytes. That's 2^15 bytes.
And `[[u64; 4096]; 64]` takes 64 times of that (i.e. 2^21 bytes, or 2 MB). It seems you have hit the stack size limit.

You could increase the stack size limit, but that would probably be a bad idea. Overall, you shouldn't try to keep too much data on the stack. Use the heap instead. There are multiple ways to do that. If you are using a [vector](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), only a pointer will be held on the stack and the data itself will be on the heap.

Comment: Interestingly [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c21ad6f22d3e84ca528c03f83a493235) suggests the limit is actually around 8MiB, unless of course the compiler is doing something clever.

Comment: @cafce25 That seems to depend on the OS and some other factors. I wouldn't rely on a particular value in general. The docs also say the limit is subject to change.

Comment: Thanks! Moving some data from arrays to vectors fixed the issue.

Comment: @cafce25 at54321 linked to the documentation for auxiliary threads, for the main thread (sometimes "process stack" it's definitely platform-specific, and would be [8MB on most unices but 1MB on windows](https://ariadne.space/2021/06/25/understanding-thread-stack-sizes-and-how-alpine-is-different/), although it might be restricted via `ulimit -s`.